# How to track changed Valued from array of objects in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an `addRows` array which contains a group of objects.

These objects are added dynamically when using click + button.

Then they are pushed to the `addRows` array; after that, the user fills these objects.

Every object has many input values such as price and quantity.

I need to change the price when the quantity changes, but the problem is if the value was added before, the returned changed item is empty.

This happens because the new value was added before in the old values array.

As shown in the image third value same first so the array returned empty value of third item

I tried foreach and for also map but I'm facing the same problem.

```
computed: {
    originalDistValue(a , b) {
        return this.addRows.map(i => {
            return i.dist
        })
    }
}, // close computed

watch: {
    originalDistValue(a , b) {
        let newVal = a.filter( obj => {
            return b.indexOf(obj) == -1;
        })

        let element = this.addRows.filter( i => {
            return i.dist == newVal;
        })

        deep: true 
        console.log(newVal)

        for(let i in element) {
            element[i].cit = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- At first create a child component for each row
- Pass each row to component
- Handle the single object inside the component instead of handling an array of objects in parent

See this example:

```js
    Vue.component('child', {
  props: {
    value: { type: Object, default: () => ({}) }
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      selfValue: null
    }
  },
  watch: {
    value: {
      handler(value) {
        this.selfValue = value
      },
      immediate: true,
      deep: true
    },
    selfVaue: {
      handler(value) {
        // you can also validate value then emit it
        this.$emit('input', value)
      },
      deep: true
    },
    'selfValue.quantity'() {
      this.selfValue.price = 0
    }
  },
  template: `
     <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
        <label>
          Title:
          <input type="text" v-model="selfValue.title" class="form-control" />
        </label>
        <label>
          Quantity:
          <select v-model="selfValue.quantity" class="form-control">
            <option value="A">A</option>
            <option value="B">B</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <label>
          Price:
          <input type="tel" v-model="selfValue.price" class="form-control" />
        </label>
     </div>
    `
})


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    rows: []
  },
  methods: {
    add() {
      this.rows.push({ title: '', quantity: '', price: 0 })
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div id="app" class="container">
  <h2 class="mb-3">Rows:</h2>

  <div v-for="row,i in rows">
    <child v-model="row"></child>
    <hr class="mt-1 mb-1" />
  </div>
  
  <button @click="add" class="mb-3">
    ADD
  </button>
  
  <pre>{{ rows }}</pre>
  
</div>
```

Comment: thank you dear, it is very useful answer ,, I an so Thankful for you

Comment: it is useful way but why this message in console "- <child v-model="row">: You are binding v-model directly to a v-for iteration alias. This will not be able to modify the v-for source array because writing to the alias is like modifying a function local variable. Consider using an array of objects and use v-model on an object property instead.
"

Comment: Your welcome. this warning can be fixed by `<child  v-for="row,i in rows" v-model="rows[i]"></child>`

Comment: hello , can you help me how to delete one of this components ? if I make any function it is delete latest item just

Comment: @OmarAlalwi you should specify a unique `key` for each component. [See this](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Maintaining-State)

Comment: I do that but it is delete index without delete component. or you mean delete it using rows[i] value?

Comment: thank you it is worked fine ,, But about validation how to use Vuelidate or any another add to make validation for each input.?